# Difference between Static Cursor Vs Dynamic Cursor in oracle

Tags: oracle

Hi Can any body describe, what are the differences between static cursor and dynamic cursor with examples.

Comment: http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/11/implicit-vs-explicit-cursors-static-vs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [ref cursors](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#LNPLS00605). For example code, [check here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/code/tips2003/042003.html). The difference is ofcourse in the ability and implementation.

Answer (score 5):

•A Static Cursor doesn't reflect data changes made to the DB once the ResultSet has been created whereas a Dynamic Cursor reflects the changes as and when they happen.

•A Static Cursor is much more performant than a Dynamic Cursor as it doesn't require further interaction with the DB server.

•A static cursor supports both Relative and Absolute Positioning whereas a Dynamic Cursor supports only Relative Positioning.

•A Static Cursor can be used for Bookmarking purposes as the data returned is static whereas a Dynamic Cursor can't be used for the same

Answer (score 2):

### **Static**

> The complete result set of a static cursor is built in tempdb when the
>   cursor is opened. A static cursor always displays the result set as it
>   was when the cursor was opened. Static cursors detect few or no
>   changes, but consume relatively few resources while scrolling.

### **Dynamic**

> Dynamic cursors are the opposite of static cursors. Dynamic cursors
>   reflect all changes made to the rows in their result set when
>   scrolling through the cursor. The data values, order, and membership
>   of the rows in the result set can change on each fetch. All UPDATE,
>   INSERT, and DELETE statements made by all users are visible through
>   the cursor.

From 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191179.aspx

Answer (score -1):

static cursor refers always one work area associated with cursor.
where as ref cursor refers different work area in memory.
ref cursor is used to declare a cursor with out select statement.